# No /var/log/jenkins directory after LTS installation

Tags: macos, jenkins

After installing Jenkins with https://www.jenkins.io/download/lts/macos/ and running it, when I go to `http://localhost:8080/`

> Unlock Jenkins

> To ensure Jenkins is securely set up by the administrator, a password has been written to the log ([not sure where to find it?](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/viewing-logs/)) and this file on the server:

So there it says:

> Log files should be at /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log, unless customized in org.jenkins-ci.plist.

But there is no `/var/log/jenkins` directory on my machine - where to find those logs? Why there is no `/var/log/jenkins` directory?

Answer (score 1):

Typically this will be written into the JENKINS home directory. Which is located at `/Users/<YOUR_USER>/.jenkins`. The secret will be located here.

```
`/Users/<YOUR_USER>/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`
```

Answer (score 0):

> and this file on the server:

It is best to rely on "this file" rather than the logs

The [official documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/macos/) suggests:

```
sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

Or (as [in here](https://www.macminivault.com/installing-jenkins-on-macos/))

```
cat /Users/administrator/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

In both instances, the file mentioned in the "Unlock Jenkins" should give you the password.

(assuming this is a Homebrew installation, not a Docker one)